# Azure ARM Template - conditional input parameter

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

**In Short:**

Is it possible to have `condition` field (or something else to achieve this functionality), inside a `parameter`, so that this parameter input will be asked to the user, only based on another parameter's value.

i.e., Only if user selects `Create New` on a parameter, the input for the name of that parameter should be asked.

---

**In Detail:**

I have a parameter `virtualNetworkCreateNewOrUseExisting` which will accept two values - `Create New` and `Use Existing`.

```
"parameters": {
    "virtualNetworkCreateNewOrUseExisting": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Create New",
        "allowedValues": [
            "Create New",
            "Use Existing"
        ]
    },
    // Other parameters
}
```

I am trying to create a `Virtual Network` based on an input from user.
If user selects `Create New`, it will be created, and if they select `Use Existing`, it will be skipped. I see that this is achievable by using `condition` field inside the `resource`.

```
"resources": [
    {
        "condition": "[equals(parameters('virtualNetworkCreateNewOrUseExisting'), 'Create New')]",
        // Other fields
    }
    // Other resources
]
```

Now, my question here is that,

**Similar to this, is it possible to have `condition` field, inside another `parameter`, so that this parameter input will be asked to the user, only based on the previous parameter value.**

i.e., Only if user selects `Create New`, the input for `Virtual Network Name` should be asked.

Something like this, by using a `condition` field:

```
"parameters": {
    "virtualNetworksName": {
        "condition": "[equals(parameters('virtualNetworkCreateNewOrUseExisting'), 'Create New')]",
        "defaultValue": "vn-1",
        "type": "string"
    },
    // Other parameters
}
```

But, I see that `condition` field, is not supported inside parameters (at least as of now).

Or, is it at least possible to have, `if` statements, like this (So that, the value of the field will be displayed `empty` by default if user selects `Use Existing`.):

```
"parameters": {
    "virtualNetworksName": {
        "defaultValue": "[if(equals(parameters('virtualNetworkCreateNewOrUseExisting'),'Create New'), 'vn-1', '')]",
        "type": "string"
    },
    // Other parameters
}
```

Or, any other way to achieve this goal?

Comment: As per the current [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#parameters), we cannot add conditions to parameters in parameters block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this natively in the template file, but in the portal user experiences for deploying the template you can...  See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-specs-create-portal-forms

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/create-uidefinition-overview

You don't *have* to use a templateSpec or managedApp (see the "Deploy to Azure button here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/demos/100-marketplace-sample )

but templateSpec or managedApp will give you a better experience if that's an option.

Answer (score 1):

As per the current [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#parameters), we cannot add conditions to parameters in parameters block.

As a side note you can use [PowerShell parameter inline functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell#inline-parameters) while deploying the template.

We see that there is a feature request already in place  to add [Support functions within the definition of parameters... · Community (azure.com)](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/31ba2f3b-0225-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8?page=1) We would suggest you to make a comment & Upvote on the exiting feedback request .